# ALSA snd_pcm_sw_params_set_stop_threshold() to a lower value cause underrun

Tags: c, linux, alsa

For mic, I understand stop threshold as: if the filled samples in soundcard hardware ring buffer crosses this threshold, the hardware stops reading from Analog to Digital converter of mic. Thus ring buffer is not over written.

For speaker, it is the maximum data that should cause stop playing audio with Digital to Analog Converter of sound card. Any further data should cause overrun.

(Correct me if I am wrong in above assumptions)

For speaker , when I set the ALSA snd_pcm_sw_params_set_stop_threshold() to a lower value , I can see underruns. I expect more overruns. Why is this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For capture devices, an overrun happens when the number of available frames (i.e., frames captured but not yet read from the buffer) reaches the stop threshold.
Overruns can happen only with capture devices.

For playback devices, an underrun happens when the number of available frames (i.e., free space in the buffer) reaches the stop threshold.
Underruns can happen only with playback devices.

Lowering the stop threshold will make xruns more likely.

Comment: This buffer is hardware buffer or ALSA maintained driver buffer ?

Comment: Yes. (It's the same buffer.)

Comment: That was a great info. Thanks CL for clarifying it.  Earlier I was thinking there were two separate buffers - one in driver and other in hardware.